terminatePostUri of azure durable function not working
I am using azure durable function to schedule a long running task that processes in chunks. Every chunk first get's data from blob storage and than process it and ingest it to adx. But when I query the terminatePostUri from the links that are provided as a result of calling this function app it doesn't terminate the function app. Rather it gives the 404 error. And I am not able to terminate the orchestrator's execution. How Can I termiante the execution of specific instance id.
Error i get is :
This localhost page can’t be foundNo web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/4535f7f23ae84e7fba5f474c11caaaa0/terminate?reason=testing&taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=aDrMZU2Qq8xLA9KWfIlDoSnY15iG608ZDIVVvDrGHE6hAzFuQndA0g==
HTTP ERROR 404
I tried to query the terminatePostUri with giving proper text in reason and expected it to termiante the orchestration but it rather thrown an error and didn't termianted that orchestartion id.

Please can you provide some code? Also - I would suggest terminating an orchestration is not the right way to do it. Perhaps you could use other mechanism to ask it to finish; but we need to see the code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The terminatePostUri works as a POST request though the request doesn't have any payload.
If you query the terminate Uri using GET request, it leads to 404 error.
To terminate the durable function, run the terminatePostUri using POST:
Query:
POST /runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/{instanceId}/terminate
    ?taskHub={taskHub}
    &connection={connectionName}
    &code={systemKey}
    &reason={text}

I have tested using the query below:
http://localhost:7208/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/<instance_id>/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=TestHubName&connection=Storage&code=rXuZMXXX3X30RSG8AzFut2JOGw==

As mentioned in MSDOC, response 410(Gone) refers to the specified instance has completed/terminated.

You can refer SO answer by @Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya for an alternate approach to terminate the durable function.
